# What is wrong with my PHP _POST that it receives all values from the form except for one?

Tags: php, html, post

I am making an online order form for the company at which I am an intern, and the form has 23 fields of misc. types.  When the end user hits submit, the form.html posts data to process.php.  The issue I am having is that the data from all of my fields gets posted, except for the data from one field.  I have checked my spelling and stuff, and the php code looks valid.  Below is the relevant code from both files, and thank you in advance for your help.

**form.html** full file here http://pastebin.com/MRwE8jE3

```
<li id="li_8" >
    <label class="description" for="prefangle">Preferred Angles </label>
    <div>
        <textarea id="prefangle" name="prefangle" class="element textarea medium"></textarea>
    </div>
</li>
```

**process.php** full file here http://pastebin.com/bSfHbt16

```
<tr><td>Preferred Angles: </td><td>".$_POST['prefangle']."</td></tr>
```

Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: Where is your full form? With form tag?

Comment: Your pastebin links doesn't contain full form nor full processing script!

Comment: did you checked if your html code is valid?

Comment: umm hold on.  ill post it, I just did not want to reveal information about company products.  redacting it now.

Comment: just add 4 whitespaces on each line and you will post it as code format.

Comment: But what field doesn't get posted?

Comment: ok added rest of code to pastebin.  I did try to add 4 spaces, and it just read the php and html without displaying it.

Comment: the preferred angle field does not get posted

Comment: Which field isn't getting posted?

Comment: Why not try `".$prefangle."` as you have for `".$separations."` etc., instead of `".$_POST['prefangle']."`?

Comment: I had to set $separations at the top, and that would work for $prefangle if I could access $_POST['prefangle']

Comment: @JPeroutek Usually what I do is define each variable at the top of a form handler, e.g. using your example field `$prefangle = $_POST['prefangle'];` and so on. I think those multiple `if(isset...)` might be doing you in.

Comment: Ok I added the $prefangle = $_POST['prefangle'] and it still did not work.  Is there a way to get around the big group of if(isset()) things that I have?  I am new to php, because i had to learn it yesterday, and that seemed the best way to handle checkboxes to me.

Comment: @JPeroutek May be a stupid question, but you did add a `;` at the end of that, right?

Comment: yes, i did.  I wish that that was all that is wrong.

Comment: @JPeroutek What are these `for="name"` as in `for="prefangle"`? I've never seen that type of coding before. Could be irrelevant.

Comment: that is to specify that the label is attached to the element with the specified name.  probably unnecessary, but it seems to work fine for all of the other fields.

Comment: @JPeroutek For the life of me, I can't find where the problem is. What if you (temporarily) renamed that field, while reflecting the changes for the rest of the form and handler?

Comment: Ok, so i found the problem and I feel incredibly stupid.  In order to save time during testing, I always hit the back button so I would not have to re-enter all of the fields.  Turns out, that was the issue.  It was using an old, invalid version of the html page, and thus could not post properly.  Sorry for wasting your time, everyone!

Comment: @JPeroutek For the life of me, when I try your code/form, I'm not getting an email. Are you in fact receiving an email, or is this done "locally"?

Comment: @JPeroutek So, what was the problem exactly, I'm curious.

Comment: @JPeroutek Yes I saw that, you said "an old, invalid version of the html page". Your old invalid html, is that what's posted in your pastebin?

Comment: umm well with firefox on this computer, when you hit back it does not get the new html file from the server, it just reloads the one it has stored in the tempfiles.  so it basically just kept reusing one with a non-working prefangles field, even though it was working.  hope that makes sense.  Thank you for taking your time trying to help me.

Comment: sorry i edited that comment accidentally.  no the one on pastebin is a valid working one, but before I was using one where the prefangle field was also called "notes"(i did some copy pasting and forgot to rename it) so it was just being overwritten 4 lines later

Comment: @JPeroutek Ok and you're welcome. Glad it worked out. I suggest that you **post it as an answer**, so the question will be marked as **resolved.** cheers

Comment: ok, will do.  can't accept my own answer for 2 days, so it will have to stay unresolved for now.

Answer (score 1):

For unknown reason, I couldn't add a comment to your question (O.O) so I'm posting it as answer (tho I do not consider it as answer, just a tip)

However, on the top of process.php, add

`print_r($_POST);`

And you'll see all the data passedby POST request :)

Comment: You dont have enough rep to add a comment - answers only for now

Comment: thanks.  showed me a big array of stuff, but prefangle is not in the list.

Comment: I've run your code locally, and it worked (prefangle got submitted). May sound stupid, but change the name of this field?

Comment: read my comment above, I found the problem.  Thank you for taking the time to comment and give me a tip though, @paranoid.

Comment: @JPeroutek haha that made my day :D

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the `<textarea>` is inside the `<form>` where the action submits it to process.php.

For debugging, you can add `var_dump($_POST);` on process.php file to see if there is really a `$_POST['prefangle']` being submitted.

Comment: prefangle is not being submitted.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I found the problem and I feel incredibly stupid. In order to save time during testing, I always hit the back button so I would not have to re-enter all of the fields. Turns out, that was the issue. It was using an old, invalid version of the html page, and thus could not post properly. Sorry for wasting your time, everyone!  If you want more details, go under comments on the question.